# Paginate Images To Similate Map Drill-Down

Tags: pagination

I apologize if this is a too easy question for you guys, but I'm newish to wordpress. I am building simple demonstration site and I need to create an image effect that enables the user to click an image and have the image exchanged for a different clickable image as to simulate a map drill-down effect using still images for 5 to 6 different levels, without leaving the current page.

Any suggestions?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Ok got some sleep... answered my question:

This effect is possible using a slider plugin.   The two plugins that I found that are able to pull this off are:

[Slider Revolution](https://www.sliderrevolution.com/) ($$ proprietary, no coding), and
[Slide Anything](https://wordpress.org/plugins/slide-anything/)  (free & pro versions, minor coding)